# How to show the same user control in different divs in a ascx file for responsiveness?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, wpf-controls, responsive

I have a control from a library registered in my other user control .ascx file and I would like to dynamically show it according to the screen size in different places in the code.

The RadMenu1 is the control in question, I do not have the original code for the control and I was not able to find a way to show and hide it just by using JavaScript based on the screen size in order to make it responsive. I could create a copy of the control, but I do not want to create a new control just for the sake of doing this.

This is a control from the Telerik.Web.UI library.

Thanks.

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Aptify.Framework.Web.eBusiness.NavBar"
    CodeFile="navbarNew.ascx.vb" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="rad" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="Aptify.Framework.Web.eBusiness" Assembly="AptifyEBusinessUser" %>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light p-0 d-md-none">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="flex-md-column flex-lg-row collapse navbar-collapse text-md-center" id="navbarTogglerDemo03" style="min-width: 200px;">
        <rad:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True" EnableShadows="True" OnItemClick="RadMenu1_click" RenderMode="Lightweight" Flow="Vertical"></rad:RadMenu>
    </div>
</nav>

<rad:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True" EnableShadows="True" OnItemClick="RadMenu1_click" RenderMode="Lightweight"></rad:RadMenu>
<cc1:User ID="User1" runat="server" />
```

I know two controls cannot have the same ID, therefore the code above gives an error saying that there is already another control with the same ID as RadMenu1.

Comment: Seems like you are using bootstrap. Bootstrap has CSS to dynamically change the menu from horizontal to vertical. Could you use the css class inside the RadMenu instead?

Comment: I can't do that because the menu orientation is controlled by the RadMenu control Flow property.

Comment: you could wrap it in a div and hide/show the wrapper div using css `@media` rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the control ID for each one like so

```
<rad:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True" EnableShadows="True" OnItemClick="RadMenu1_click" RenderMode="Lightweight"></rad:RadMenu>

<rad:RadMenu ID="RadMenu2" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True" EnableShadows="True" OnItemClick="RadMenu2_click" RenderMode="Lightweight"></rad:RadMenu>

<rad:RadMenu ID="RadMenu3" runat="server" EnableRoundedCorners="True" EnableShadows="True" OnItemClick="RadMenu3_click" RenderMode="Lightweight"></rad:RadMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you! That would be the answer to this question, but it turned out I would have to create a new RadMenu in the back end so I decided to use a Web Service instead for dryness.